# DB delays connection when request

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, circular-dependency

I am establishing a connection to the DB But there are somethings weird happening

Some requests given to the backend server Responds with `User is not associated to Bill` ( User and Bill are tables in my Sequelize ORM and they have one2Many relation
But when I do some requests to the server the error disappears ( Maybe the error appears only when the first request made after some period of time  'The server establish a connection  to the DB finishes' )

And due to that in my db there are some mistakes happens as you can see in the image below ( In the BillId. ProductId column for example)

the way I initialized the connection to the DB is as you can see (Probably here is the mistake but i really dont know why exactly)

```
// bill.model.js
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../../config/db');

const Bill = db.define(
  'Bill',
  {
    // ... Columns definistions
  },
);
Bill.associations = function associations(models) {
  Bill.hasMany(models.BillItem);
  Bill.belongsTo(models.User);
};
module.exports = { Bill };
```

and here where i create the connection ..

```
// config/db.js
const db = new Sequelize(DB_URL, {
  logging: false,
});

(async () => {
  try {
    await db.authenticate();


    // IS THIS ERROR BECAUSE OF THOSE ?
    const { BillItem } = require('../modules/bill_item/bill_item.model');

    const { Product } = require('../modules/product/product.model');

    const { Bill } = require('../modules/bill/bill.model');

    const { User } = require('../modules/user/user.model');

    await User.associations({ Bill });
    await Bill.associations({ User, BillItem });
    await BillItem.associations({ Product, Bill });
    await Product.associations({ BillItem });

    await db.sync();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to connect with the DB: ', error);
  }
})();

module.exports = db;
```

Note

```
// When i want to use a model I just import it 
const { Bill } = require('../bill/bill.model');
```

NULL in the ModelID is the un expected thing happen
[image: DB]